# ColdFusion ext-all.css messing up page formatting

Tags: css, coldfusion, padding

I have a master-page sort of setup where a master page is loaded and clicking on different tabs loads different sub-pages within the page. One of my pages works well when loaded directly in a browser, but when loaded within the master page the formatting is messed up - all the headers are compressed/squished, spacing is off... I tracked it down to the following css being applied from CF's ext-all.css file (there is a cfajaximport tag in the master page which seems to be causing it to be included):

```
html, body, div, dl, dt, dd, h1, h2, h3, h4, h5, h6, pre, form, fieldset, input, p, blockquote, th, td {
    margin: 0;    
    padding: 0; 
}
```

Why is this included in ext-all.css (it seems to mess up most default padding/spacing of headers, tables, etc)? How can I get around this, other than a) tampering with ext-all.css, and b) overriding the margin and padding css for these tags in the individual file?

Comment: This is what you get for using elements of the CFML language that are widely recommended against by pretty much the entire community. They are not fit for purpose. The solution is to *not* use those UI elements.

Comment: @AdamCameron - We're _not_ using the UI elements in the page - there are just several old pages linked to this master page that use them and still need to be supported :P Eventually we hope to rewrite them.

Comment: Are you using `cfwindow, cfform,cflayout` or any UI related tags in your code?

Comment: a) tampering with ext-all.css

Good option if you are not using cfwindow, cfform,cflayout etc.

Comment: "there are just several old pages linked to this master page". So that'd be you using them then. Perhaps you just need to rationalise yer code so that the import for the resources are closer to where you use them?

Comment: @AdamCameron - I was just pointing out that I don't have the option of not using the UI elements because I have old code that I don't want to break. The new page does not use them. Are you suggesting using cfajaxinclude in all the individual files that need them that are loaded within the master page, rather than using cfajaxinclude in the master page?

Answer (score 0):

A quick and pragmatic way for me was just overriding the specific css definitions. An older project uses **cfmap**, and without rewriting the code, I simply did this in my case:

```
.x-border-box, .x-border-box * {
    box-sizing: content-box !Important;
    -webkit-box-sizing: content-box !Important;
}

.x-body{
    font-family:lato,​Helvetica,​"Arimo",​sans-serif;
    font-size:15px;
    color:#444; 
}
```

The page rendered correctly again.
Depending on what ui-tag you use, override the ext-css definitions.

Because the scripts/styles are prepended to the HEAD (before your own styles), you can't use "inherit", but have to explicitly set the css property (as I did with font-family, size and color and in my case with box-sizing).

But try to avoid using those tags as suggested. you don't have full control, it messes with addiontal scripts and styles and increases pageload.

In my case the problem showed when moving from cf9 to cf11 (updated version of ext-all.css).
Hope it helps! 
(thanks Reto for the box-sizing-fix!)